# How to copy information between multiple spreadsheets only if common data (name) in one column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm using multiple Google Sheets to set up a logging system for the transfer of students between classrooms during a study period. A master spreadsheet (I call it Spreadsheet A) contains a record of all the students in the building and the teacher to whom they are assigned, and each teacher has their own separate spreadsheet (Spreadsheets B1, B2, etc.) tracking only the students assigned to them. There are more than 100, which is why I opted for separate spreadsheets rather than giving each teacher a tabbed page in Spreadsheet A.

Teachers can request that a specific student be sent to them for help by entering their name next to the student's name on the master list (Spreadsheet A). When this happens, the student's name is added to a list on the spreadsheet of the teacher making the request (so that's Spreadsheet B1). Separately, the student's regular homeroom teacher sees the student's name highlighted on *their* page (Spreadsheet B2), and sees which teacher made the request. Spreadsheet A feeds all the information to the various Spreadsheet Bs

This is all done and built. However, we want to include a time-tracking function, to make sure that students are moving in a timely fashion and not disappearing. Currently, the teacher *receiving* the student enters the time they showed up on Spreadsheet A, but this is cumbersome. The teachers want a way to enter arrival times on their own pages, and have it visible to the sending teacher & the administration.

So, I want the main Spreadsheet A to pull data from teachers' Spreadsheet Bs, look for students who have arrival times listed, and then copy those arrival times into a data column next to the students' names on the master list on Spreadsheet A. That will, in turn, propagate out to their homeroom teacher and administrator, so they can see who's coming and going, and how long it's taking them.

Oh, and there are nearly 2,000 students, so there's no way to put in a search string name by name. It has to be a blanket formula that says:

- If there is data in column K (an arrival time) on Spreadsheet B1 (and all other B-series spreadsheets),
- Then use the data in column H (the student's name),
- Find a match on the master list on Spreadsheet A,
- And copy that data from Spreadsheet B1 into column F (Arrival time test) on Spreadsheet A, next to the appropriate student, but
- Do nothing if there is no data in column K.

Is this even possible?

Test demonstration page:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1F2HYmGv8Vfw9TDeAI2eNmv73jCD-lWcfhKZvWM8-r58/edit#gid=0

The pages for each teacher can be opened from the links in the second page tab.

So far, I've tried to compile all of the data from the existing teacher spreadsheets (B1, B2, etc.) into one list as a page on Spreadsheet A. I thought this would then make it easier to match the names and times, but it always throws an error message, no matter what formula variation I try.

```
=QUERY({Importrange("1y4GjGnUK9usYCNnSClYl2piFgMlbn07wWClrgZnl6Ms","’Teacher page’!H6:K");Importrange("1dNNZR0GvskBU2WG2N348EGFDbHN2aK9kWmxhoQNmn2M","’Teacher page’!H6:K")},"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col1 is not null ")
```

This produces: "Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2"

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1y4GjGnUK9usYCNnSClYl2piFgMlbn07wWClrgZnl6Ms","Teacher page!H6:K");IMPORTRANGE("1dNNZR0GvskBU2WG2N348EGFDbHN2aK9kWmxhoQNmn2M","Teacher page!H6:K");IMPORTRANGE("1buhv3AAi6apWIg_-uZv_BzDvyOEvpkxTmO5is-Yhxi4","Teacher page!H6:K");IMPORTRANGE("1b-kEed3zFcZIg3eldcT0x0JXgiwfWNUou_N0ntPsVEg","Teacher page!H6:K")})
```

This produces a result, but only from the first Spreadsheet B (B1) queried. It doesn't include the results from the other three sheets in the test version. I still have no idea how I'd merge the data from that data collection to the original master list.

Comment: did you solve it or you still in need of solution?

Comment: Using names as unique IDs will come back to bite you. John Smith A and John Smith B might be different people!